# Como posso construir um loop com a grid bootstrap em diversos tamanhos?

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap, while, grid

Atualmente estou trabalhando com wordpress e veio a seguinte duvida...

Meu atual loop se encontra assim... (8 Itens)

```
      COL-MD-6                     COL-MD-6        
    --------------------------   --------------------------

      COL-MD-6                     COL-MD-6        
    --------------------------   --------------------------

      COL-MD-6                     COL-MD-6        
    --------------------------   --------------------------
```

Porem preciso de algo assim...

```
      COL-MD-4              COL-MD-4             COL-MD-4        
    -----------------   -----------------  ----------------

      COL-MD-6                       COL-MD-6                  
    --------------------------   --------------------------

      COL-MD-4              COL-MD-4             COL-MD-4        
    -----------------   -----------------  ----------------
```

Caso alguem possua a solução, agradeço muito!

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a lógica seja essa:

```
<?php

$count = 0;  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $count++;?>

    <?php if( $count <= 2 ) { ?>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

    <?php } elseif ( $count >= 3  and $count  <= 5) {   ?>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">

        <?php if( $count == 5 ){ ?>

            <?php $count = 0; ?>

        <?php } ?>

    <?php } ?>

            <!-- seu código aqui -->

        </div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Boa tarde, entendi mais ou menos o que você quiz fazer, mas não ficou do jeito que eu queria, ficou meio q random os tamanhos... porem agradeço o empurrão, irei tentar ajustar esse código! Obrigadooo mann!

Comment: Eu fiz um teste aqui e funcionou da forma que você mencionou, me passa mais detalhes de como era para ficar que eu te ajudo.

Comment: Opa! beleza? deu certo depois, eu que vacilei aqui ahahaha! funcionou sucesso meu queridoo! obrigadãao!